# How to get getSelectedView() to work in GridView?

Tags: java, android, selection

I have a `GridView` in a layout. It is populated with `Foo` views by the activity using a extended `BaseAdapter`.

When I select an item in this grid it gets orange tinted (thus selected). That's nice. But I want to access this selection from outside the GridView and it's parent activity: from within another `View` higher in the layout hierarchy. I therefor call upon `gridView.getSelectedItem()`. However it always returns `null`.

How could I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Selection" doesn't mean the same thing in AndroidOS as it does in other UIs. In particular, there **isn't** any "selected item" when you're in touch mode. You probably need to use a [click listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) instead of relying on there being a "selected item". See [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html) for details.

Comment: I found it to be correct that I should have the child View to communicate to the parent View, instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get the view:

```
View childView = gridView.getChildAt(position - gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
```